# How to store values of hash in array in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash having duplicate values and unique keys.I have to store keys in array of size 5, if more keys are there new array should be created and stored in it.
The keys stored in 1 array should have same value.

Note: I have to read those values from excel sheet and generate c source file.

Ex:
    %hash = (a=>1,b=>2,c=>1,d=>1,e=>3,f=>4,g=>4,h=>1,i=>1,j=>1);

output in c file:

```
datatype arr1[]={a,c,d,h,i};
datatype arr2[]={j};
datatype arr3[]={b};
datatype arr4[]={e};
datatype arr5[]={f,g};
```

Comment: Re "*I have a hash having duplicate keys*", That's not possible. That's like someone saying they have an array with duplicate indexes.

Comment: Thats why i made reverse having duplicate values and unique keys.These values i have to read from excel sheet.

Comment: Please fix the question by editing it, not by adding a comment.

Comment: A few lines of example data and expected result would probably make it more clear what you want…

Answer (score 0):

So you need to find keys that have the same values?

So we need to kind of revert the array, but being a bit smart to handle that the original values are not unique. Som instead of just transforming 'key' => 'value' pairs to 'value' => 'key', we need to store the keys in arrays.

```
my %hash = ...;

my %transposed;
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    my $value = $hash{$key};

    $transposed{$value} = [] unless defined $transposed{$value};
    push @{ $transposed{$value} }, $key;
}
```

Then you have a hash of arrays, where each key is a value in the original hash and the elements of the arrays are the keys. The next step is to iterate over the keys and spilt each list into lines of 5 elements:

```
for my $key (sort keys %transposed) {
    while (@{ $transposed{$key} }) {
        my @list = splice @{ $transposed{$key} }, 0, 5;
        say join ", ", @list;
    }
}
```

The main parts is the while loop iterating as long as there are elements in the current list and the splice removes and returns up to 5 element from the list each iteration. Adding the exact C code is left as an exercise for the interested reader... :-)

You might need to read up on references: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

The line setting a hash value to a reference to an empty array is not necessary as perl will automatically create a arrayref when you tries to push a value to it. I have included it to make it clearer what is going on.